# How to make the the timer running when app is locked in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-service

I am running the timer but when my app is locked the timer is paused so how can I make my timer running in the background. I think I should use a background service but I don't know how to use it.

```
var timer = Timer()  
var sec = 0
var min = 0
func startTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }
     
     
     
 @objc func updateTimer() {
      sec += 1
      let sq = sec / 60
      min += sq
      if sec == 60 {
         sec = 0
      }
        
      timerLabel?.text = "\(min):\(sec)"
  }
```

Comment: you cant use no longer background services, what's the concept u try

Comment: You can't and you don't need to.  Incrementing a counter isn't a very accurate of tracking elapsed time. Create a `Date` when you start the timer and then your elapsed time is `timeIntervalSinceNow` on that `Date`

Comment: I might add to @PaulW11 - which is correct - that your use of the word *"locked"* is what caught my eye - it's probably a language thing, but there really isn't a concept of "locked" in iOS. Technically, it's that your app have either been move into a background state by the OS or forced-shutdown by either the OS or the user.